# Legit javascript UTC Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I've been looking for a way to keep my dates in UTC in my JS application; however, in every case the Date's `getTimezoneOffset()` does not return a `0` which, I would imagine, should be the case -- and which would be seemingly important in casting dates between UTC and the local TZ.

See below examples of what I've tried, thanks in advance for any insight!

```
var TheDate = new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 10, 5) );
console.log(TheDate.getTimezoneOffset()) // => 300 (for me)
```

```
console.log(moment().utc().toDate().getTimezoneOffset()) // => 240 (for me)
```

Comment: The `getTimezoneOffset()` is the offset when you are formatting your date with `.toString()`. It is meaningless when you are formatting your date with `.toUTCString()`. Notice that its value is not a property of your date object at all, it's your environment's locale, and you cannot do anything to change that.

Comment: From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) ~ _"returns the time zone difference, in minutes, from **current locale (host system settings)** to UTC"_

Comment: So then, I should comprehend that Dates don't have timezones, rather the machine has a timezone.

Comment: @Bergi You can do something to change it. `process.env.TZ = 'UTC'`.

Comment: @Paul I think that's what I'm going to do, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Paul Ah, I missed the node.js tag, but anyway, it's irrelevant to what the timezone is set when using only utc methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECAMScript Dates are inherently UTC and are just an offset from the ECMAScript epoch (a time value in milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z), nothing more. They have no associated timezone.

The host timezone offset is used:

1. When creating a Date to determine the equivalent UTC time and calculate the time value
2. In various methods that use local dates and times, such as *getHours* (vs *getUTCHours*)

The date itself does not know anything about timezones.

The value returned by *getTimezoneOffset* is based on the host system settings, the only relationship it has to the Date it's called on is that the offset is calculated for that Date. The method might be called *getHostSystemTimezoneOffset*, because that's what it returns.

In your code:

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 10, 5))
```

creates a Date for 2012-11-05T00:00:00Z. Calling *getTimezoneOffset* on that date returns the host system offset for the equivalent local date and time, not the offset that was used in creating the Date.

There is no way to associate a timezone with a date without using a library (either one you write or one of the many existing libraries).

In your second example:

```
moment().utc()
```

just sets a flag to tell moment.js methods to use UTC for everything. Then using:

```
....toDate().getTimezoneOffset()
```

returns a Date object, then gets the host system timezone offset for that date as if you'd done:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

If you want to only use UTC, then use *UTC* methods for everything and ignore timezones completely (which I think is what you want to do).